# What does `from six.moves import urllib` do in Python?

Tags: python

I found the following line in Python code:

```
from six.moves import urllib
```

Simultaneously, I can find `urllib.py` anywhere. I found that there is a file `six.py` in package root and it has `class Module_six_moves_urllib(types.ModuleType):` inside.

Is this it? How is this defined?

**UPDATE**

Sorry I am new to Python and the question is about Python syntax. I learned, that what is after `import` is Python file name without a `py` extension. So, where is this file in this case?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

[six](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six) is a package that helps in writing code that is compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3.

One of the problems developers face when writing code for Python2 and 3 is that the names of several modules from the standard library have changed, even though the functionality remains the same.

The `six.moves` module provides those modules under a common name for both Python2 and 3 (mostly by providing the Python2 module under the name of the Python 3 module).

So your line

```
from six.moves import urllib
```

imports `urllib` when run with Python3 and imports a mixture of `urllib`, `urllib2` and `urlparse` with Python2, mimicking the structure of Python3's `urllib`. See also [here](https://six.readthedocs.io/#module-six.moves).

**EDIT** to address the update of the question:

TLDR; There is not necessarily a direct relation between the imported module `urllib` and a file on the filesystem in this case. The relevant file is exactly what `six.__file__` points to.

Third party modules are defined in a file/directory that is 
 listed in [`sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.path). Most of the time you can find the name of the file a module is imported from by inspecting the `__file__` attribute of the module in question, e.g. `six.__file__`. However with `six.moves` things are not as simple, precisely because the exposed modules might not actually map one to one to actual Python modules but hacked versions of those.