# Use python requests to download CSV

Tags: python, csv, python-requests

Here is my code:

```
import csv
import requests
with requests.Session() as s:
    s.post(url, data=payload)
    download = s.get('url that directly download a csv report')
```

This gives me the access to the csv file. I tried different method to deal with the download:

This will give the the csv file in one string:

```
print download.content
```

This print the first row and return error: _csv.Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field

```
cr = csv.reader(download, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
for row in cr:
    print row
```

This will print a letter in each row and it won't print the whole thing:

```
cr = csv.reader(download.content, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
for row in cr:
    print row
```

My question is: what's the most efficient way to read a csv file in this situation. 
And how to download it.

thanks

Answer (score 121, accepted):

This should help:

```
import csv
import requests

CSV_URL = 'http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv'


with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(CSV_URL)

    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')

    cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(cr)
    for row in my_list:
        print(row)
```

Ouput sample:

```
['street', 'city', 'zip', 'state', 'beds', 'baths', 'sq__ft', 'type', 'sale_date', 'price', 'latitude', 'longitude']
['3526 HIGH ST', 'SACRAMENTO', '95838', 'CA', '2', '1', '836', 'Residential', 'Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008', '59222', '38.631913', '-121.434879']
['51 OMAHA CT', 'SACRAMENTO', '95823', 'CA', '3', '1', '1167', 'Residential', 'Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008', '68212', '38.478902', '-121.431028']
['2796 BRANCH ST', 'SACRAMENTO', '95815', 'CA', '2', '1', '796', 'Residential', 'Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008', '68880', '38.618305', '-121.443839']
['2805 JANETTE WAY', 'SACRAMENTO', '95815', 'CA', '2', '1', '852', 'Residential', 'Wed May 21 00:00:00 EDT 2008', '69307', '38.616835', '-121.439146']
[...]
```

Related question with answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33079644/295246

---

Edit: Other answers are useful if you need to download large files (i.e. `stream=True`).

Comment: Is it necessary to read the entire thing into memory?  This seems non-scaleable.

Comment: I notice this doesn't always maintain structure of csv. I'm downloading a csv with a Notes column and the notes have newlines in them. Using this solution, all newlines are ignored and its not ideal

Answer (score 39):

To simplify these answers, and increase performance when downloading a large file, the below may work a bit more efficiently.

```
import requests
from contextlib import closing
import csv
from codecs import iterdecode

url = "http://download-and-process-csv-efficiently/python.csv"

with closing(requests.get(url, stream=True)) as r:
    reader = iterdecode(csv.reader(r.iter_lines(), 'utf-8'), 
                        delimiter=',', 
                        quotechar='"')
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

By setting `stream=True` in the GET request, when we pass `r.iter_lines()`  to csv.reader(), we are passing a **[generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)** to csv.reader(). By doing so, we enable csv.reader() to lazily iterate over each line in the response with `for row in reader`.

This avoids loading the entire file into memory before we start processing it, drastically reducing memory overhead *for large files*.

Comment: I had to also `import codecs` and wrap the `r.iter_lines()` within `codecs.iterdecode()` like so: `codecs.iterdecode(r.iterlines(), 'utf-8')` ... in order to solve `byte` vs `str` issues, unicode decoding problems and universal new line problems.

Comment: Thanks @IrvinH. , I ran into the same problem. btw it should be r.iter_lines() you missed the underscore.

Comment: On Python 3.7 this results in:  error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Answer (score 14):

I like the answers from [The Aelfinn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3923962) and [aheld](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1259640). I can improve them only by shortening a bit more, removing superfluous pieces, using a real data source, making it 2.x & 3.x-compatible, and maintaining the high-level of memory-efficiency seen elsewhere:

```
import csv
import requests

CSV_URL = 'http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs1004/a16/Resources/SacramentoRealEstateTransactions.csv'

with requests.get(CSV_URL, stream=True) as r:
    lines = (line.decode('utf-8') for line in r.iter_lines())
    for row in csv.reader(lines):
        print(row)
```

Too bad 3.x is less flexible CSV-wise because the iterator must emit Unicode strings (while `requests` does `bytes`) while the 2.x-only version—`for row in csv.reader(r.iter_lines()):`—is more Pythonic (shorter and easier-to-read). Anyhow, note the 2.x/3.x solution above won't handle the situation described by the OP where a NEWLINE is found unquoted in the data read.

For the part of the OP's question regarding *downloading* (vs. processing) the actual CSV file, here's another script that does *that*, 2.x & 3.x-compatible, minimal, readable, and memory-efficient:

```
import os
import requests

CSV_URL = 'http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~cs1004/a16/Resources/SacramentoRealEstateTransactions.csv'

with open(os.path.split(CSV_URL)[1], 'wb') as f, \
        requests.get(CSV_URL, stream=True) as r:
    for line in r.iter_lines():
        f.write(line+'\n'.encode())
```

Comment: Best answer!  Works great with latest version of Python.

Comment: To support the widest audience, it *should* work with all currently-deployed versions of Python, not just the latest... thx though! :-) (min version is 2.6)

Comment: For downloading, I think most users will want `f.write(line + '\n'.encode())` - currently your example writes one enormous line which won't be easily loaded back into memory by a CSV reader

Comment: Thx for spotting that. I normally try to take advantage of the "free" `\n` that comes w/text files but neglected to recall that respectable libraries drop those for the purpose of data-scrubbing, requiring us to add them back when creating our own files w/such data.

Answer (score 10):

You can also use the [`DictReader`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) to iterate dictionaries of `{'columnname': 'value', ...}`

```
import csv
import requests

response = requests.get('http://example.test/foo.csv')
reader = csv.DictReader(response.iter_lines())
for record in reader:
    print(record)
```

Comment: `_csv.Error: iterator should return strings, not bytes (the file should be opened in text mode)`

Comment: This should be a comment, not a separate answer.

Answer (score 6):

I use this code (I use Python 3):

```py
import csv
import io
import requests

url = "http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv"
r = requests.get(url)
r.encoding = 'utf-8'  # useful if encoding is not sent (or not sent properly) by the server
csvio = io.StringIO(r.text, newline="")
data = []
for row in csv.DictReader(csvio):
    data.append(row)
```

Comment: Thanks. I just had to change the encoding to "utf-8-sig" and it worked.

Answer (score 5):

To convert to Pandas DataFrame:

```
from io import StringIO
text=StringIO(download.content.decode('utf-8'))
df=pd.read_csv(text)
```

Answer (score 4):

From a little search, that I understand the file should be opened in universal newline mode, which you cannot directly do with a response content (I guess).

To finish the task, you can either save the downloaded content to a temporary file, or process it in memory.

Save as file:

```
import requests
import csv
import os

temp_file_name = 'temp_csv.csv'
url = 'http://url.to/file.csv'
download = requests.get(url)

with open(temp_file_name, 'w') as temp_file:
    temp_file.writelines(download.content)

with open(temp_file_name, 'rU') as temp_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(temp_file, dialect=csv.excel_tab)
    for line in csv_reader:
        print line

# delete the temp file after process
os.remove(temp_file_name)
```

In memory:

(To be updated)

Answer (score 3):

You can update the accepted answer with the iter_lines method of requests if the file is very large

```
import csv
import requests

CSV_URL = 'http://samplecsvs.s3.amazonaws.com/Sacramentorealestatetransactions.csv'

with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(CSV_URL)

    line_iterator = (x.decode('utf-8') for x in download.iter_lines(decode_unicode=True))

    cr = csv.reader(line_iterator, delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(cr)
    for row in my_list:
        print(row)
```

Answer (score 2):

I used below solution (Unfortunately others did not work for me):

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('http://.../file.csv')
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 1):

The following approach worked well for me. I also did not need to use `csv.reader()` or `csv.writer()` functions, which I feel makes the code cleaner. The code is compatible with Python2 and Python 3.

```
from six.moves import urllib

DOWNLOAD_URL = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gjreda/gregreda.com/master/content/notebooks/data/city-of-chicago-salaries.csv"
DOWNLOAD_PATH ="datasets\city-of-chicago-salaries.csv" 
urllib.request.urlretrieve(URL,DOWNLOAD_PATH)
```

Note - six is a package that helps in writing code that is compatible with both Python 2 and Python 3. For additional details regarding six see - [What does `from six.moves import urllib` do in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34989206/what-does-from-six-moves-import-urllib-do-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Python3 Supported Code

```
    with closing(requests.get(PHISHTANK_URL, stream=True})) as r:
        reader = csv.reader(codecs.iterdecode(r.iter_lines(), 'utf-8'), delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
        for record in reader:
           print (record)
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked nicely for me:

```
from csv import DictReader

f = requests.get('https://somedomain.com/file').content.decode('utf-8')
reader = DictReader(f.split('\n'))
csv_dict_list = list(reader)
```

Comment: This loads everything in memory at once, though.

Answer (score 0):

Python 3.x:

For anyone trying the solutions above, if you are getting a `\ufeff` at every new line, just change the encoding from `utf-8` to `utf-8-sig`.

If you only want the CSV in string format, simply access the `.text` property of the request, like this:

```
req = requests.get("https: ...")
req.encoding = 'utf-8-sig'
csv_data = req.text
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to handle the csv data

**To download csv data into a DataFrame**

```
url = 'https://cdn.wsform.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/color_srgb.csv'

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(url)
print(df.head())
```

You should be able to see the output:

```
     Name      HEX               RGB
0   White  #FFFFFF  rgb(100,100,100)
1  Silver  #C0C0C0     rgb(75,75,75)
2    Gray  #808080     rgb(50,50,50)
3   Black  #000000        rgb(0,0,0)
4     Red  #FF0000      rgb(100,0,0)
```

**To download csv data into a csv file**

```
import requests
import os

resp = requests.get(url)
with open('temp.csv', 'w') as f:
    f.write(resp.content.decode('utf-8'))
print('File saved in:', os.getcwd())
```

You should be able to see the saved file in the current working directory (use `os.getcwd()` to see the current working directory)