# how to grab a csv url

Tags: python, r

I have run into this problem before and still don't know what I can do, so I figured I would ask here.

Say I have a website like: https://www.macrotrends.net/stocks/charts/AAPL/apple/stock-price-history

if you scroll down a bit there is a red button "Download Data". This downloads the csv.

I would like to read this csv into a data frame in Python or R. Whatever 'read csv' function I use, I need a url. My question is: How do I get a url for this csv? That's all I need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are looking for the url for this specific case, and not a general solution for similar cases, if that is the case, I think this is the url you are looking for:

http://download.macrotrends.net/assets/php/stock_data_export.php?t=AAPL

The way I found it was

1. Load the url from the question
2. RMB on download button and click **Inspect Element** (I used Opera, but I know chrome has an equivalent)
3. Open the console (tab on top of inspection pane)
4. Clicked the red download button you mentioned
5. Watched the console until I saw something that looked like it was fetching something and tried that url

It seems like a bit of a hack, but it downloads the data.

Since you mentioned python, @HEADLESS_0NE has a good answer on how to [Use python requests to download CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371043/use-python-requests-to-download-csv/35371451)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I figured I could get it by expecting elements, but beyond that I had no idea, so now I can apply this to other sites that do the same thing