# Load csv from url behind login page into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, authentication, python-requests

I try to load a csv-file into pandas dataframe, but the csv-file is only accessable after login.

So far, it downloads and `print(decoded_content)` to screen, but I can't figure out how to load the csv into pandas dataframe:

```
import requests
import urllib2
import pandas as pd
import csv


headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/133.35 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.2041.120 Safari/521.14'
}

login_data = {
    'username': 'myusername',
    'password': 'mypassword',
    'stayloggedin': '0',
    'login': 'Login'
}

with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://www.domain.tld/en/login.html'
    r = s.get(url, headers=headers)
    r = s.post(url, data=login_data, headers=headers)

    a = s.get('https://www.domain.tld/path/to/file/data.csv')
    decoded_content = a.content.decode('utf-8')

print (decoded_content)
```

.

```
Col1;Col2;Col3
0102;120;212
121;122;331
```

Comment: maybe selenium could help you?

Comment: @user1438644 I'm a total rookie and just began learning python and pandas for data science. I already looked into selenium, but I don't understand it. :/ The above code is fine, but I simply can't figure out how to call the CSV behind the login.

Comment: Could you try this - ```opener = urllib2.URLopener()``` and ```opener.retrieve('https://www.domain.tld/path/to/file/data.csv')```

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/41880513/7782271

Comment: This might help: [Use python requests to download CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371043/use-python-requests-to-download-csv)

Comment: @ Ramin Melikov: HTTP: 403. @M.Sqrl: This worked and I updated my question, but I still cant get csv into the damn pd dataframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2020/04/21 Edit

Solution:

I created `TestFile.csv` with your data:

```
Col1;Col2;Col3
0102;120;212
121;122;331
```

Important to note that separator is semi-colon.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('TestFile.csv', sep=';')
print(df)
print(type(df))
```

Output:

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3
0   102   120   212
1   121   122   331
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Description of [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) There are a lot of parameters because .csv files are not governed by a strict set of rules.