# Downloading a csv from a url sometimes fails

Tags: python, csv, url, python-requests, download

I used the codes below to extract historical data from `nasdaq.com` but it failed.

```
import pandas as pd
link = "https://www.nasdaq.com/api/v1/historical/BFC/stocks/2015-07-12/2020-07-12"
data = pd.read_csv(link, skiprows=2)
print(data)
```

Then I tried another code below but also failed.

```
import csv
import requests

csv_url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/api/v1/historical/BFC/stocks/2015-07-12/2020-07-12/'
req = requests.get(csv_url)
url_content = req.content
csv_file = open('downloaded.csv', 'wb')
csv_file.write(url_content)
csv_file.close()
```

But the codes above work for some other url links like
`https://www.ishares.com/de/professionelle-anleger/de/produkte/270048/ishares-msci-world-value-factor-ucits-etf/1478358465952.ajax?fileType=csv&fileName=IS3S_holdings&dataType=fund&asOfDate=20180731`

Anyone could advise?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use python requests to download CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371043/use-python-requests-to-download-csv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a header with user-agent to the request
The header should be in dict format

```
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
```

So your code with requests will be:

```
import csv
import requests
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
csv_url = 'https://www.nasdaq.com/api/v1/historical/BFC/stocks/2015-07-12/2020-07-12/'
req = requests.get(csv_url, headers=headers)
url_content = req.content
csv_file = open('downloaded.csv', 'wb')
csv_file.write(url_content)
csv_file.close()
```

Comment: amazing! it works. got to know that the user-agent is created to fake the website.

Comment: Plz vote and confirm that my answer solve your problem @C.C