# how to download and iterate over csv file

Tags: python-3.x, csv, python-requests

I'm trying to download and iterate over csv file but I'm only reading the headers but no more lines after it
tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35371043/use-python-requests-to-download-csv) answer but with no luck
this is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
import requests
import csv


def main():
    print("python main function")
    datetime_object = datetime.now().date()
    url = f'https://markets.cboe.com/us/equities/market_statistics/volume_reports/day/{datetime_object}/csv/?mkt=bzx'
    print(url)
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    csv_content = response.content.decode('utf-8')
    print(csv_content)
    cr = csv.reader(csv_content.splitlines(), delimiter='~')
    my_list = list(cr)
    for row in my_list:
        print(row)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `yfinance` can get equity volumes. Do you have to download a CSV?

Comment: @OneCricketeer  I want to insert all the data from the csv file to mt db

Comment: I understand that. You still get a dataframe with that library that you can iterate over

Comment: In any case, what happens if you just use `for line in csv_content.splitlines()` and skip using a csv.reader ?

Answer (score 0):

```
cr = csv.reader(csv_content.splitlines(), delimiter='~')
```

change to

```
cr = csv.reader(csv_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
```

And check if You download full file or file with header only use URL in browser ;)