# Retrieving CSV file from URL

Tags: pyscript

I’m trying to read a csv file from a url using pyscript.  (To eventual load into pandas, not shown in my example.)  Following the example here, https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/guides/http-requests.html, I’m able to use pyfetch to retrieve  the example payload, which appears to be json.  However, I can’t seem to use it to retrieve a csv file (or any other non-json payload.)

An example is below.  The first download works; the second does not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <py-script>
        import asyncio
        import json
        
        from pyodide.http import pyfetch

        
        async def main():
            # This works
            url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/2"
            response = await pyfetch(url)
            print(f"status:{response.status}")

            # This does not work
            url = "https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/datasets/csv/turtles.csv"
            response = await pyfetch(url)
            print(f"status:{response.status}")


        asyncio.ensure_future(main())
    </py-script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I should note, I did find a couple pyscript tutorials on csv files specifically; however, they appear to use deprecated approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyScript has a builtin feature to allow loading of remote files into the in-browser filesystem called [[[fetch]] configurations](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/reference/elements/py-config.html#local-modules). These remove the need to rely on open_url directly.

A fetch configuration can take several keys - in your case, the `from` key fetches the content from a given URL, and places the content in a folder in the in-browser filesystem (that Python has access to) in a file that looks like te last part of that URL's path. (In this case, `turtles.csv`).

You can also use the `to_file` key to specify a different filename, or the `to_folder` key to place that file within a different folder in the in-browser filesystem.

```html
<py-config>
    packages = [
        "numpy",
        "pandas",
        "jinja2"
    ]
    [[fetch]]
    from = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fomightez/pyscript_test/main/turtles.csv'
</py-config>

<py-script>
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_csv('turtles.csv')
    Element("pandas-output").element.style.display = "block"
    display (df.head().style.format(precision=2), target="pandas-output-inner", append="False")
</py-script>
```

Comment: this is nice; thank you.  Do you have any idea as to why the original url does not work, https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/datasets/csv/turtles.csv?

Comment: It looks like the server that stores that file doesn't have the appropriate headers to allow general access. When using that URL, in the browser dev console I see: `Access to fetch at 'https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/datasets/csv/turtles.csv' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5501' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.` You can read more about this CORS issue here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS/Errors/CORSMissingAllowOrigin

Answer (score 0):

When you just click this link, the csv is getting downloaded in the local. So the file is existing.
https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/datasets/csv/turtles.csv

The following code worked.
import pandas as pd

URL = "https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/datasets/csv/turtles.csv"
data=pd.read_csv(URL)
print(data)

Comment: Thank you for the answer; however, my understanding (and experience) is that you can't use that approach in pyscript because pyodide does does not have the requests module.

Answer (score -1):

Hmmm... the download from your site is tricky. I cannot see why it won't work with `open_url` when your site behaves the same as `https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets.holoviews.org/data/nyc_taxi_wide.csv` when I access each in m browser. And `https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets.holoviews.org/data/nyc_taxi_wide.csv` works with `open_url`. So that rules out it being any Cross Origin Resource problem (CORS).

And it is even odder since as MuthuSankaraNarayanan Valliamm points out `data=pd.read_csv('https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/datasets/csv/turtles.csv')` works when run in a typical, full Python kernel.

And the following based on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371451/8508004) works in a typical Python kernel, too:

```py
# based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/35371451/8508004
import csv
import requests

CSV_URL = 'https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/datasets/csv/turtles.csv'


with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(CSV_URL)

    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')
    print(decoded_content)

    cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(cr)
    for row in my_list:
        #print(row)
        pass
```

**Maybe someone will point out how to make your source work with pyscript?** For now I moved your data to GitHub.

**Below is an example that links to the actual CSV data URL where I moved your data to GitHub.**

---

## Solution: use `open_url` to get CSV

Often the Pyscript demonstrations include more useful examples than the higher level guides, such as https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/guides/http-requests.html . Getting a CSV boils down to `df = pd.read_csv(open_url(url))` as demonstrated

#### They have an example getting a CSV you can adapt

Importantly for you, there is an offered example called NYC Taxi Data Panel DeckGL Demo that includes getting data as a CSV file among those listed on [the Pyscript demos page](https://pyscript.net/examples/). It is found **presently** under the 'Visualizations & Dashboards' section [there](https://pyscript.net/examples/), which is way at the bottom presently:

- link to 'NYC Taxi Data Panel DeckGL Demo' pyscript example running served on web: [here](https://pyscript.net/examples/panel_deckgl.html)
- link to the code for 'NYC Taxi Data Panel DeckGL Demo' pyscript example on Github: [here](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/blob/main/examples/panel_deckgl.html)

Adapting your code to that example to focus on getting the CSV:

- See the adapted version running on the web [here](https://fomightez.github.io/pyscript_test/csv_apr_2023_test.html).
- The adapted code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="default" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#0072b5" />
    <meta name="name" content="CSV Getting Demo adapted from PyScript/Panel DeckGL Demo" />

    <title>CSV Getting Demo</title>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./favicon.png" />
    <link
        rel="stylesheet"
        href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css"
    />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/examples/assets/css/examples.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="pandas-output" hidden>
        <h3>Output</h3>
        <div id="pandas-output-inner"></div>
    </div>
    <py-tutor>
            <py-config>
                packages = [
                  "numpy",
                  "pandas",
                  "jinja2"
                ]
                plugins = [
                  "https://pyscript.net/latest/plugins/python/py_tutor.py"
                ]
            </py-config>

            <py-script>
                import pandas as pd

                from pyodide.http import open_url

                url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/fomightez/pyscript_test/main/turtles.csv'
                df = pd.read_csv(open_url(url))
                Element("pandas-output").element.style.display = "block"
                display (df.head().style.format(precision=2), target="pandas-output-inner", append="False")
            </py-script>
        </py-tutor>
    </section>
</body>
</html>
```

You can run that right here by clicking the 'Run code snippet' button. Because of the small area and the dataframe being displayed in the top of a section, **I found I needed to then click on 'Full page' view option that will then come up on the right side in order to see the dataframe well.** You can get back to the post by clicking on 'Close' in the upper right from the full page view.)

Comment: This is great; thank you @Wayne.  The unlock for me was the pyodide open_url.

Comment: Hmmm....so it works for you? Maybe it is CORS. I'm not having luck getting your link to work from code running here or on GitHub.

Comment: I should add, the source of the data seems to have created an unneeded complication.  I had choose it somewhat at random for the example.

Comment: Hmmm...but `https://s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/assets.holoviews.org/data/nyc_taxi_wide.csv` acts the same as yours but maybe Amazon buckets allow CORS. Weird. Glad the example with `open_url` helped in the end. That's definitely the main point, to use `open_url`.