# Trying to read csv file from static folder with python

Tags: python, flask, pyscript

I have a flask web app setup with the folder structure below

```
app
 -website
     -static
         ---example.csv
     -templates
         ---home.html
     -__init__.py
     -views.py
 -main.py
```

my home.html file where I try to access the csv file using pyscript

```
<py-script>
file = open("./static/example.csv", mode="r", encoding="utf-8")
</py-script>
```

I get

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 44] No such file or directory
```

when I test my app in the browser

I have tried also `/static/example.csv`, `website/static/example.csv`, `127.0.0.1:5000/static/example.csv`. The last one finds the csv file if I type it in the browser.

Comment: At this point you are just guessing the working directory. Just use `import os ; print(os.getcwd())` to verify it

Comment: I'm not following what pyscript example you are following here and expecting it to work? Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and note that the second emphasized section heading is 'Search, and research'. Read [here](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/146#issuecomment-1116072063) as to why you cannot do that the way you are attempting. Then skip all the way to the bottom for the current last two posts [here](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/146#issuecomment-1790197387) and ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://github.com/pyscript/pyscript/issues/146#issuecomment-1790750075) as the best solution has changed over the last few months. Indeed that penultimate approach about `[[fetch]]` has an example with code by the developer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148659/8508004). The approach with `[files]` I haven't found a good example for yet, especially one that is self-contained just uses HTML. And I note all the examples so far still use `open_url` that I illustrate on [the same page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76148659/8508004) as `[[fetch]]` example. For example, ....

Comment: <continued> see [this Pandas example](https://pyscript.com/@examples/pandas/latest) that is at [the pyscript examples page](https://pyscript.com/@examples). I have [example code using `[[fetch]]` here](https://github.com/fomightez/pyscript_test/blob/main/csv_Mar_2024_fetch_test.html) that runs with [this working example on web at GitHub Pages here](https://fomightez.github.io/pyscript_test/csv_Mar_2024_fetch_test.html). (FWIW: The non-working attempt with `[files]` key use is there as well: [code](https://github.com/fomightez/pyscript_test/blob/main/csv_Mar_2024_files_key_test.html) ...

Comment: <continued>  ; [Demo link](https://fomightez.github.io/pyscript_test/csv_Mar_2024_files_key_test.html).)

Comment: **Update**: Thanks to JeffGlass, I know have gotten the version with the newer `[files]` key working. [Working demo is here](https://fomightez.github.io/pyscript_test/csv_Mar_2024_files_key_test.html) and the code for that is [here](https://github.com/fomightez/pyscript_test/blob/main/csv_Mar_2024_files_key_test.html). As detailed in [his post here](https://jeff.glass/post/whats-new-pyscript-2023-11-1/) a lot has changed and I find that the `py-config` section is more sensitive now. So I'd suggest when using it to simplify first and then add things in to see if it breaks it.